# explicit creation type not conforming to type of target

Tags: polymorphism, eiffel

I really don't understand as it seems to me the basics of type conformance. I have a `Creation instruction lists explicit creation type which does not conform to type of target` on `create {JANITZA_DEVICE} l_device.make_from_file_path (a_file_path)` with eiffel studio 19.5 enterprise.

[image: class schema]

### SMA_INVERTER_MANAGER_CSV

```
class
    SMA_INVERTER_MANAGER_CSV

inherit
    SUNSPEC_DEVICE_CSV[SMA_INVERTER_MANAGER_DEVICE]

create
    make
```

### SUNSPEC_DEVICE_CSV

```
deferred class
    SUNSPEC_DEVICE_CSV[G -> SUNSPEC_DEVICE create make_from_file_path end]

inherit
    CONSUMPTION_SECTOR_CSV[G]
        redefine
            process_file,
            set_header_csv
        end

feature --

    process_file (a_file_path: PATH)
        require else
            attached a_file_path.entry
            attached consumption_sector
        local
            l_device: like devices.item
        do
            check
                attached_consumption_sector: attached consumption_sector
            then
                if is_valid_file_path (a_file_path) then
                    if attached a_file_path.utf_8_name.has_substring ("janitza_UMG604") then
                        create {JANITZA_DEVICE} l_device.make_from_file_path (a_file_path) -- The compiler doesn't agree!
                    else
                        create l_device.make_from_file_path (a_file_path)
                    end
                    l_device.load_measuring_point (create_measuring_points, measuring_point_db_service, consumption_sector)
                    devices.extend (l_device)
                    Precursor (a_file_path) -- load measure_units from csv_row
                    devices.wipe_out
                end
            end
        ensure then
            devices.is_empty
        end
```

### CONSUMPTION_SECTOR_CSV[G]

```
deferred class
    CONSUMPTION_SECTOR_CSV[G -> MEASURING_POINT_DEVICE]

feature -- Access

    devices: LINKED_SET[G]
```

### SUNSPEC_DEVICE

```
class
    SUNSPEC_DEVICE

inherit
    MEASURING_POINT_DEVICE
        redefine
            default_create,
            set_measuring_point,
            out
        select
            serial
        end

    MODBUS_DEVICE
        rename
            serial as modbus_serial,
            set_serial as set_modbus_serial
        undefine
            make
        redefine
            default_create,
            make_from_file_path,
            name_from_file_path,
            out
        select
            set_modbus_serial
        end

create
    make_from_file_path
```

### JANITZA_DEVICE

```
class
    JANITZA_DEVICE

inherit
    SUNSPEC_DEVICE
        redefine
            set_measure_units,
            name_from_file_path
        end

create
    make_from_file_path
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified case:

```
class ANIMAL

class CAT inherit ANIMAL

class HOUSE_CAT inherit CAT

class DOG inherit ANIMAL
```

```
class
    ENCLOSURE [G -> ANIMAL]
feature
    specimens: LIST [G] --> The actual type will vary with the generic parameter

    describe
        do
            print(specimens.generating_type)
        end
```

```
class
    APPLICATION

feature

    test
        local
            l_cat: CAT
            l_animal_enclosure: ENCLOSURE [ANIMAL]
            l_cat_enclosure: ENCLOSURE [CAT]
            l_house_cat_enclosure: ENCLOSURE [HOUSE_CAT]
            l_dog_enclosure: ENCLOSURE [DOG]
        do
            create l_specimen

            create l_animal_enclosure
            l_animal_enclosure.describe --> LIST [ANIMAL]
            l_animal_enclosure.specimens.add (l_cat) --> Fine, CAT conforms to ANIMAL

            create l_cat_enclosure
            l_cat_enclosure.describe --> LIST [CAT]
            l_cat_enclosure.specimens.add (l_cat) --> Fine, CAT conforms to CAT

            create l_house_cat_enclosure
            l_house_cat_enclosure.describe --> LIST [HOUSE_CAT]
            l_house_cat_enclosure.specimens.add (l_cat) --> ERROR, CAT does not conform to HOUSE_CAT


            create l_dog_enclosure
            l_dog_enclosure.describe --> LIST [DOG]
            l_dog_enclosure.specimens.add (l_cat) --> ERROR, CAT does not conform to DOG
        end
```

In your case, `devices: LINKED_SET [G]` is too vague, nothing proves that `JANITZA_DEVICE` is a valid type because `G` might end up being lower down the hierarchy (like `HOUSE_CAT` -> `CAT`; you cannot substitute a `CAT` to a `HOUSE_CAT`, thus a list of `HOUSE_CAT` cannot accommodate a `CAT`) or in a separate branch of the hierarchy (like `DOG` -> `ANIMAL`; a dog is not a cat, they only share a common ancestor).

If `{ENCLOSURE}.specimens` was declared as `LIST [ANIMAL]` instead of `LIST [G]`, `describe` would always print `LIST [ANIMAL]` regardless of the actual generic parameter because the type would not vary, thus the previous code would compile and run just fine.
Similarly, if `{CONSUMPTION_SECTOR_CSV}.devices` was declared as `LINKED_SET [SUNSPEC_DEVICE]` instead of `LINKED_SET [G]`, it could accommodate all descendants of `SUNSPEC_DEVICE` regardless of the actual type of `G`.

Alternatively, you could move the parts specific to `JANITZA_DEVICE` from `CONSUMPTION_SECTOR_CSV` to a descendant of `CONSUMPTION_SECTOR_CSV` where `G` is closed, as in

```
class
    JANITZA_CONSUMPTION_SECTOR_CSV -- No generic here!
inherit
    CONSUMPTION_SECTOR_CSV [JANITZA_DEVICE]
        redefine
            process_file -- Add the parts specific to `JANITZA_DEVICE` in the implementation
        end
```

which would ensure that `devices` can hold instances `JANITZA_DEVICE`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to edit as code, I edited the answer and completed it with a picture, hope it helps. Thx for your answer, but still do not understand why it doesn't conform, as `JANITZA_DEVICE` a heir of `SUNSPEC_DEVICE`, and its create method is conform to definition of `G`

Answer (score 0):

I think that user10481525 has explained the reason for the error. Your code doesn't guarantee that `JANITZA_DEVICE` will conform to `G` in all potential descendants of `SUNSPEC_DEVICE_CSV`.

You have declared the attribute `devices: LINKED_SET [G]`. Therefore, the local variable `l_device: like devices.item` would be of type `G`. Attaching a `JANITZA_DEVICE` to it might be invalid in a descendant of `SUNSPEC_DEVICE_CSV`. Why? Because `G` could be any descendant of `SUNSPEC_DEVICE`.

For example, suppose you had a descendant `class FOO_DEVICE_CSV inherit SUNSPEC_DEVICE_CSV [FOO_DEVICE]`; where `class FOO_DEVICE inherit SUNSPEC_DEVICE`. Your local variable would effectively resolve to `local l_device: FOO_DEVICE`. Therefore, the descendant would be trying to attach an object of type `JANITZA_DEVICE` to it. But that's invalid, because `JANITZA_DEVICE` doesn't conform to `FOO_DEVICE`:

`feature devices: LINKED_SET [FOO_DEVICE]
...
local l_device: FOO_DEVICE
...
create {JANITZA_DEVICE} l_device.make_from_file_path (a_file_path) -- Invalid!`

Comment: Thx for your effort, I unfortunatedly still didn't got it :-(