# How to specify when giving a generic parameter that it should implement some specific creation method?

Tags: generic-collections, eiffel

How to specify when giving a generic parameter that it should implement some specific creation method? as `LIST[G -> create make end]` doesn't work :-(

[image: class diagram]

In my particular case, 
  * `SMA_INVERTER_MANAGER_CSV` has inherited from `CONSUMPTION_SECTOR_MODBUS_DEVICE_CSV`a list of devices as `devices: LINKED_SET[G]` as `G -> MEASURING_POINT_MODBUS_DEVICE create make_from_file_path end`.

I'd like the `SMA_INVERTER_MANAGER_CSV` class to be able into `devices: LINKED_SET[G]` to be able to have either JANITZA_DEVICE, SUNSPEC_DEVICE, ABB_DEVICE, etc. Giving the generic parameter as MEASURING_POINT_MODBUS_DEVICE seems to come out of a sense, but how do I specify that I'd like the creation method to be `make_from_file_path`

Hope the description is sufficient to understand, refactoring I think this question is linked -> [explicit creation type not conforming to type of target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58368872/explicit-creation-type-not-conforming-to-type-of-target/58369180#58369180)

The only workaround for the moment I found working for the moment is

```
class
    SMA_INVERTER_MANAGER_CSV

inherit
    CONSUMPTION_SECTOR_MODBUS_DEVICE_CSV[SUNSPEC_DEVICE]

create
    make


end
```

but I'd like it to be

```
class
    SMA_INVERTER_MANAGER_CSV

inherit
    CONSUMPTION_SECTOR_MODBUS_DEVICE_CSV[MEASURING_POINT_MODBUS_DEVICE]

create
    make


end
```

which would generate a conformance problem because `MEASURING_POINT_MODBUS_DEVICE` generic parameter doesn't specify `make_from_file_path` as creation procedure as its deferred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than a conformance problem. `MEASURING_POINT_MODBUS_DEVICE` is deferred. Therefore, it cannot be used as an actual parameter for `CONSUMPTION_SECTOR_MODBUS_DEVICE_CSV`. If it were allowed, how would `CONSUMPTION_SECTOR_MODBUS_DEVICE_CSV` create an instance of a deferred class?

One possible solution — supplying an effective class — is mentioned in the question. Another solution is to add a formal generic parameter to `SMA_INVERTER_MANAGER_CSV` with the corresponding constraint and to use it for the actual generic of `CONSUMPTION_SECTOR_MODBUS_DEVICE_CSV`.

Comment: `how would CONSUMPTION_SECTOR_MODBUS_DEVICE_CSV create an instance of a deferred class` good point! That gave me the key of the reason why!

Comment: So solution 1) would be having an effective class which for my example would be to undefer the MEASURING_POINT_MODBUS_DEVICE class, but doing that I'd remove what makes sense for me which is obligate at compile time the descendants to implement `set_measure_units` procedure, I seem to be obligated to redefine it and being unable to have it deferred. So a workaround as at compile time its impossible to solve my problem would be to add a `check implement_it: False end` into its implementation at `MEASURING_POINT_MODBUS_DEVICE` level. Is there any other solution?

Comment: @Pipo What about solution 2 mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Actually it was what I intented to do but did not understand how to make it :-(

Comment: @Pipo Instead of fixing the parameter in `SMA_INVERTER_MANAGER_CSV`, it might be possible to keep it: `SMA_INVERTER_MANAGER_CSV [G -> ...]` would inherit `CONSUMPTION_SECTOR_MODBUS_DEVICE_CSV [G]`. Clients of the class would then specify an effective actual parameter as needed, e.g. `SMA_INVERTER_MANAGER_CSV [ABB_DEVICE]`.